# Linking to a different view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink

I am new to Rails and I'm not sure how to link to a different view I just created. I am on the index view now, and I want to link to the eat.html.erb view that is inside the same folder. Do I have to add code to the controller just to set this up? I would think adding code to the controller just so I can link to a view sounds like a bit of unnecessary work.

Comment: A rails book will help you greatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you would like to accomplish you need to create a show action in the controller with "def eat". Your code on the view should be...

```
<%= link_to "TITLE OF PAGE HERE", FOLDERNAME_eat_path %>
```

I would recommend using 'a href' for what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, you create a link with the link_to method of the url helper: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html

Here's an example:

```
<%= link_to "eat", eat_path %>
```

However, your question indicates that you don't quite have a grasp of the rails basics*. Sergio has suggested you get a book, but a good/free place to start learning is here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

You should go through that from start to end and you will get a pretty good understanding of the basic concepts in rails.

*You're asking to link to a partial (which starts with an underscore), which isn't actually a page.

Comment: Good answer, I'd also recommend http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book which is also free.

Comment: I understand that example. I had that prior to coming here. The name of the folder is 'Foods'. So I used <%= link_to "eat", foods_path %>. This only links me to /foods. I am trying to go to /foods/eat.html.erb. I could just use <a href="#"> but I was curious if there were another way.  I think it's just a lot of extra work to be required to edit the routes and controller just so a user can add a new link to a page.

Comment: Rails isn't really designed for static websites. It makes interaction with the database and other things really easy but for what you're trying to do you'll need to jump through a few hoops. You'll at least need a `foods_controller` and some routes setup in config/routes.rb like `get ':controller/:action'` then you'll be able to link to '/foods/eat'. I don't think you need to include an action in the controller if the view already exists.

Comment: Thanks I have it now. I had to add to my routes `get 'food/eat' => 'food#eat'`. I had to add def eat to the controller with `@eat = Food.where(:tag => 'Eat')`. If I didn't add to controller I would get get a `'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compaitable object. It must implement :to_partial_path`